# KeysView, ValuesView and ItemsView default representation of a Mapping subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, inheritance

One can easily create a `dict`-like class by subclassing `collections.Mapping`. However if I use the default `keys`, `values` and `items` methods of `Mapping` it seems the returned types (`collections.KeysView`, `ValuesView` and `ItemsView`) just show the class representation.

A very simplistic example:

```
from collections import Mapping

class MyDict(Mapping):
    def __init__(self, dct):
        self._dct = dct

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._dct[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._dct)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._dct)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{self.__class__.__name__}({self._dct})'.format(self=self)
```

In interactive use this displays as:

```
>>> a = MyDict({'a': 10})
>>> a.keys()  # shows the complete dictionary
KeysView(MyDict({'a': 10}))
>>> a.values()  # also shows the complete dictionary
ValuesView(MyDict({'a': 10}))
```

I want it to be more like what `dict` has:

```
>>> d = {'a': 10}
>>> d.keys()  # shows only the keys
dict_keys(['a'])
>>> d.values()  # shows only the values
dict_values([10])
```

I found some ways to make them do what I want but it makes the class much more complicated (because I need to subclass `KeysView`, `ValuesView`, `ItemsView` and overwrite the `keys`, `values` and `items` method):

```
from collections import Mapping, KeysView

class KeysViewOnlyKeys(KeysView):
    # Subclass that just changes the representation.
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{self.__class__.__name__}({keys})'.format(self=self, keys=list(self))

class MyDict(Mapping):
    def __init__(self, dct):
        self._dct = dct

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._dct[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._dct)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._dct)

    def keys(self):
        # Overwrite this method to use the representation-changed subclass
        return KeysViewOnlyKeys(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{self.__class__.__name__}({self._dct})'.format(self=self)

>>> a = MyDict({'a': 10})
>>> a.keys()
KeysViewOnlyKeys(['a'])
```

Is there some easy way to get these Views to `repr` just the requested parts or is something wrong in the `MyDict`-class? It seems much too complicated to subclass these `View`s and override the methods manually.

Comment: But this is only the representation. I do not get why this is so important. Actually the first representation is more accurate since if you write this in the console, you will construct an object that is again represented that way...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Not necessarily important (it gave me a hard time when trying to debug a function that used my Mapping so it's not really unimportant either) but it's definetly different from `dict` and `collections.OrderedDict` (the other standard mappings also use `dict_keys`). I don't think it's more accurate when it does something else than the standard library - that it's (not) sensible to copy a `View` is quite another question. I just want my class to have a similar `keys` representation.

Comment: There's no need to subclass `KeysView`, just return `self._dct.keys()` in `MyDict.keys()`.